# how to slim down view controllers in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, delegates

How you guys slim down your view controllers?, sometimes you end up implementing a lot of protocols in your view controller, so there’s a lot of code inside the controller itself. Reading about how to slim down view controllers in iOS I found that a common way is to move DataSources (http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html) to other class, but what about other delegates?, or if you create views by code?. First, I think about move each delegate to a NSObject class, so I try this:

```
self.locationManager.delegate = [[FRRYPetDescriptionViewControllerLocationDelegate alloc] init];
```

Then I ask in IRC and somebody suggest categories, so this is what I got so far:

```
// FRRYPetDescriptionViewController.h
@interface FRRYPetDescriptionViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (nonatomic) TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *contentView;

@end

// FRRYPetDescriptionViewController+Protocols.h
@interface FRRYPetDescriptionViewController (Protocols) <UITextViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

// FRRYPetDescriptionViewController+UIAdditions.h
@interface FRRYPetDescriptionViewController (UIAdditions)

- (void)createScrollView;
- (void)createContentView;

@end

// FRRYPetDescriptionViewController+Callbacks.h
@interface FRRYPetDescriptionViewController (Callbacks)

@end

// FRRYPetDescriptionViewController+LocationAdditions.h
@interface FRRYPetDescriptionViewController (LocationAdditions)

@end
```

This makes me think, what about “private” methods?, do I need to declare all properties in the view controller header file?. What you guys think about this approach or there’s some common pattern to follow to not end with a fat controller?.

Thank you.

Comment: check this: http://www.objc.io/issue-13/mvvm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link that you have referred to has beautiful explanation for less bulky controller's programming. But techniques are bit tricky unless you are a seasoned developer. You have asked about multiple techniques in your question. Please check my views on them below: -

**Delegates** - I personally prefer to keep the delegate code in my controller itself to avoid unwanted confusion specially when you are working with multiple scenarios within the same controller.
**Create Views Programmatically** - This is the portion where we can cut the large amount of code from UIViewController. Unless it is a single control such as a single label or button, we should make a custom UIView class and let it set all the common properties for view customisation. Controller should only invoke it with necessary parameters.
**Properties in Header File** - No, concept of data encapsulation says that we should only make those variables public which are required. Rest should move to private domain so that we external objects can't interfere with the class object functionality. So you should declare these properties in class extension (inside .m file). Moreover it is not required to have all variables as properties, when they are private you can declare them as instance variables as property declaration does nothing but to create the getter/setter for that variable.
**Private Methods** - Same goes to methods as well. If it doesn't have to be exposed to other objects; it should not be in header file. Keep it in extention as private method.